# Delay in server response, apache2 codeigniter

Tags: php, performance, apache, codeigniter

Noticing a long delay in server processing time. The application environment is:
  Apache2
Ubuntu 10.04
PHP 5.3
Codeigniter 2.1
first call after a time causes a significant delay
codeigniter profiler is enabled and gives this feedback
Loading Time: Base Classes      2.7587
Controller Execution Time ( Home / Index )      7.2188
Total Execution Time 9.9777
There are only 2 database active record queries both taking less than a 10th of a second.
I am  not using any kind of cache.
However the same page on refreshing yields this by the codeigniter profiler
Loading Time: Base Classes      0.0074
Controller Execution Time ( Home / Index )      0.1471
Total Execution Time    0.1545

From +9 seconds to almost tenth of  a second.
This time there are 2 more database queries (codeigniter session fetch and updtate)
Is there something i can modify to to reduce the time when a new session is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter in opposite to Zend is already lighted. Try comment unused libraries.

Comment: I am loading only one library!

Comment: I mean, check application/config.php for libraries not used (mailing, parsing, etc)

Comment: config/config.php and config/autoload.php are not loading any libs.  Also if some other libs were being loaded, could this explain the difference in times in the 2 situations mentioned above?

Comment: Long loading issue might not be related to CodeIgniter. This can happen if server disks are overloaded (or network drives used). But, because files are cached (on server) there is no easy way to check it out.

Comment: My hosting company is most like to say that i have low ram (256 MB), which should not be a problem because the mysql is located remote.

Comment: Here is what worked! I contacted my hosting company rackspace. and the live chat told me about this command hdparm -tT /dev/sda1. The hard drive access was pain fully slow. Apparently there was some user who was swapping seriously, and hurting all other users. They moved me to a new machine. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

There is no doubt it's something wrong with your server installation.

I use Ubuntu 11.04 with the last XAMPP and it works great, try reinstalling your server.

Comment: there are other apps on the same server, they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of database driver do you use? are they differs with the other page? cause i have faced this problem too. 
i use mysql database server version 5.X.X.
i use CI 2.0.3

this is the report from the profiler

using driver mysql

---

Loading Time: Base Classes      0.4485
Controller Execution Time ( Single Import / Get Dpt Count By Region )   0.1042
Total Execution Time    0.5531

using driver mysqli

---

Loading Time: Base Classes      1.4436
Controller Execution Time ( Single Import / Get Dpt Count By Region )   1.1049
Total Execution Time    2.5488

so i suggest you to only use mysql driver, i still don't any clue(don't have time to debug :D) if there is a problem with CI when try to load mysqli driver cause the load base classes significant than the other one(mysql). i hope this can help you. :)